# how to show content in activity?

Tags: java, android

if I run it it cannot show the contents of the main activity.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.usernameEditText);
        password = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.passwordEditText);
        register = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.registerTextView);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null ){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
        }
```

this is the on click listener of the login

```
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validate(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

this is the onClickListener of the register btn.

```
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class) );
            }
        });
```

[Here is the screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hicN.jpg

Comment: what are the contents not showing ? can you explain more ? can you attach any screenshots

Comment: Your question needs more clarity.